# When writing big O notation can unknown variables be used?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I do not know if the language I am using in the title is correct, but here is an example that illustrates what I am asking.

What would the time complexity for this non-optimal algorithm that removes character pairs from a string?

The function will loop through a string. When it finds two identical characters next to each other it will return a string without the found pair. It then recursively calls itself until no pair is found.

Example (each line is the return string from one recurisive function call):

```
iabccba
iabba
iaa
i
```

Would it be fair to describe the time complexity as `O(|Characters| * |Pairs|)`?
What about `O(|Characters|^2)` Can pairs be used to describe the time complexity even though the number of pairs is not knowable at the initial function call?

It was argued to me that this algorithm was `O(n^2)`because the number of pairs is not known.

Comment: Pairs can be used to calculate complexity, but only insofar as you must pick the most expensive value. Play with large inputs. Graph size of input (7 in your case) to number of iterations (4). Pick larger and larger inputs. You do not look at the relationship between 7 and 4. That's just one datapoint. You look at the curve of the graph as input-size grows towards infinity. Your algorithm is O(n) (I think).

Comment: This can be done in `O(|string| + number of pairs)`. No need to iterate from the beginning after dropping pair. Just continue from where you stopped to drop the pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that this is strictly speaking `O(|Characters| * |Pairs|)`

However, in the **worst case**, number of pairs can be same as number of charachters (or same order of magnitude), for example in the string 'abcdeedcba'
So it also makes sense to describe it as `O(n^2)` worst-case.

I think this largely depends on the problem you mean to solve and  and it's definition.
For graph algorithms for example, everyone is comfortable with a writing as complexity `O(|V| + |E|)`, although in the worst case of a dense graph `|E| = |V|^2`. In other problems we just look at the worst possible case and write `O(n^2)`, without breaking it into more specific variables.

I'd say that if there's no special convention, or no special data in the problem regarding number of pairs, `O(...)` implies worst-case performance and hence `O(n^2)` would be more appropriate.